# change drawing cursor on canvas with fabric.js

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

i'm using fabric.js to make a drawing tool canvas. i want to change the cursor while i'm drawing so i'm using this:

```
canvas.freeDrawingCursor = 'url('icn_pencil.svg), auto';
```

this is working and i can see the image cursor.

my problem is that i need to change the image position because otherwise  it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can tell where the hit-point is by using coordinates right after the url:

```
canvas.freeDrawingCursor = 'url('icn_pencil.svg) x y, auto';
```

Replace `x` and `y` above with the offset values in pixels matching the image.

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
c.onmousemove = function(e) {ctx.fillRect(e.clientX - 2, e.clientY - 2, 4, 4)};
```

```css
html, body {margin:0}
#c {
  cursor: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fp7eL.png) 4 64, auto;
  background:#ddd;
  }
```

```html
<canvas id=c width=600 height=600></canvas>
```